# Quebrar Colunas Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

estou fazendo uma estrutura com `bootstrap`, conforme as "leis" do `bootstrap` deve-se usar `col-xs-12 col-md-12` estou fazendo 2 colunas principais com colunas dentro, exemplo:

[EXEMPLO CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/furlann/pen/yeXaOy)

a coluna da direita, tem colunas filhas com `col-xs-12 col-md-6`, só que uma tem um tamanho maior que a outra, fazendo com que nao fique 2 colunas na mesma linha, o que pode estar dando errado?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 borda">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Titulo
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        CONTEUDO
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 borda">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Titulo
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>CONTEUDO</p>
          <p>CONTEUDO</p>
          <p>CONTEUDO</p>
          <p>CONTEUDO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Titulo
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>CONTEUDO</p>
          <p>CONTEUDO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Titulo
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Conteudo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poste o código aqui também, é sempre recomendado que se poste no site o código, para que seja independente de outros sites.

Comment: O `Bootstrap` só está sendo responsivo. Se ele não possui espaço abaixo de outra div, ele simplesmente alinha a direita. E siga o que o Diego comentou e poste o código dentro do SOPT.

Comment: pronto @LucasHenrique

Comment: Não entendi direito o seu problema.. Você deseja que a coluna da direita, que possui outras 3 divs, alinhe as 2 primeiras em uma mesma linha, é isso?

Comment: isso @CelsomTrindade em cada linha 2 colunas, sem precisar o uso da div `row` pq vou inserir essas divs com `jQuery`, ai precisa ficar 2 colunas por linha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não deseja utilizar a classe `row` para agrupar as linhas, o mais correto é você atribuir um `height` para as `divs` da coluna da direita.

```
<div class="col-md-6 minhaDiv></div>

.minhaDiv {
    height:250px;
}
```

---

#### Editado:

Para ficar um layout mais harmônico, você pode aplicar a propriedade de `height` na classe `panel`, o resultado será o mesmo e o visual fica melhor, conforme solicitado nos comentários.

```
<div class="col-md-6>
    <div class="panel">...</div>
</div>

.panel {
    height:250px;
}
```

Veja: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoEjxz?editors=110

Ou, uma alternativa já que você está utilizando e irá inserir as `divs` via `jQuery`, seria de pegar a maior altura dentre as `divs` a serem exibidas e aplicar ela à todas as outras através de um `.css()`.

Comment: Resolve, mas fica estranho um espaço em branco neh kkk

Comment: Atualizei o pen, Na verdade é só você aplicar o height à classe `.panel` assim o espaço em branco fica só dentro dele. Veja se fica melhor

Comment: blz, vlew @Celsom obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Eu vejo 3 situações em seu HTML:

1) A soma das colunas da primeira "camada" de colunas é menor que 12.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- a primeira poderia ser 'col-md-4' -->
    <div class="col-md-2 borda"> ... </div> 
    <div class="col-md-8 borda"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) O conteúdo da primeira coluna vc dividiu em mais colunas, porém não aninhou com uma `row`:

```
<div class="col-md-2 borda">
<!-- Aqui deveria ter um div row -->
  <div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
<!-- Aqui deveria ter um div row -->
</div>
```

3) O conteúdo da primeira coluna vc dividiu em mais colunas, porém a soma é maior que 12.

```
<div class="col-md-8 borda">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja se não é essa combinação de configuração que está atrapalhando o funcionamento correto do [Boostrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: O somatório não é problema e não deve interferir em nada além do visual. Se for uma galeria de imagens ou página de portfólio, por exemplo, teríamos mais de 2 divs com certeza, e o col-md-6 seria usado apenas para determinar quantas divs por linha nós teríamos, não necessariamente ter que fechar o somatório de 12 dentro de uma row.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, vdd. Mas a falta de rows ou falta de preenchimento das colunas, pode trazer comportamento inesperado. Mas, vc está certinho.

Comment: Sim sim, esse meu comentário não se aplica apenas na sua 3ª observação (que é onde está o problema do AP), as demais estão corretas.

Answer (score -1):

Você só precisa criar um `row` pai e duas `row` filhas dentro dele. Isso define que, dentro de uma linha (com X colunas) você vai possuir mais duas linhas dentro.

Segue exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div id="linha1" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
               <!-- Content -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="linha2" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
               <!-- Content -->
            </div>
         </div>
      </div> 

      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <!-- Content -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Caso queira ver esse código em seu funcionamento, segue a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p8v225x7/1/).

Comment: é disso que to falando : https://jsfiddle.net/8ku9ymcy/

a coluna é menor, ai ela vai embaixo, teria que ficar 2 colunas na linha, sem precisar usar o row, e o height

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema, apenas deixa mais complexo ainda. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/p8v225x7/2/

Comment: vou fazer um exemplo com jQuery de como eu quero

Comment: @CelsomTrindade tipo assim: http://codepen.io/furlann/pen/yeXaOy

Comment: @Furlan veja se minha resposta resolve seu problema.